# How can I automatically publish my questions and their responses to my blog?

Tags: linkedin-api, blogger, stackexchange, stackexchange-api

I want to publish my questions and their responses asked here (on Stack Overflow) to my blog (or Linkedin, etc.) automatically.

I host my blog on blogger.com.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you at least half an answer.  If you can get the information from Stackoverflow, then you can easily write a program to write posts using the [Blogger API](http://code.google.com/apis/blogger/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html).  The structure of your program would need to be something like

1. Get info from Stackoverflow.
2. Authenticate with Blogger using one of the authentication methods.
3. Create the HTML for the post body based on the Stackoverflow info.
4. Combine that with meta data tags to create the post entry (atom format).
5. Create a new post using the string you created in the last step.

If you run into problems with any of those steps, other than the first one, I'm sure I could help you further.  Just ask here on Stackoverflow and tag it with 'blogger' and I'll try to answer.

Comment: On first one, follow doc https://api.stackexchange.com/docs, if facing  any issue, you can drop question here at http://stackapps.com/ and tag  with api-v2